# How to handle a onClick method in a component?

Tags: reactjs

I believe I have my props setup correctly, but I keep getting "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

Child component:

```
 const SearchResults = props => (
     <div>
    <div className="row" ><h4 style={{margin:"auto", marginBottom:"15px"}}>Search Results:</h4></div>
      <table className="table table-striped">
       <thead>
         <tr>
          {props.labels.map(label => ( <th key={label.Id}>{label.DisplayName}</th>))}
         </tr>
       </thead>
      <tbody>
{ props.contracts.map((contract, i) => <tr key={i} data-id={contract.Id}  onClick={() => this.props.handleContract(contract.Fields.filter(field => field.DataField==="IDXT001").map(field => field.DataValue))} className="clickable-row">{contract.Fields.map( docs =>  <td key={docs.Id}><span id={docs.DataField}>{docs.DataValue}</span></td>)}</tr> )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
   )
```

Parent:

```
class SearchPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        labels: [],
        contracts: [],
        formValues:"",
        pdfs:[],
        id:"",
      };
    }
<SearchResults 
    labels={this.state.labels}
    contracts={this.state.contracts} 
    pdfs={this.state.pdfs}
    handleContract={this.onClick}
/>
```

Comment: Can you show us the entire component where you try the onClick? Is it a function component?

Comment: handleContract={this.onClick} did you bind onClick already in your constructor?

Comment: You can't use `this` keyword inside function components like you'd do in class components. `This` is simply undefined in function components. You would accept a `props` parameter in function declaration and call a function this way `props.handleContract(...args)`

Comment: @G_S I added this.handleContract = this.handleContract.bind(this); to the constructor but still get the same error "props.handleContract is not a function"

Comment: @DenisJ, you have not used handleContract as your function's name in parent component. You have passed `handleContract={this.onClick}` - This means your functions name is onClick.

Comment: @Avanthika Yes you are correct. I changed to this.onClick = this.handleContract.bind(this); and now it works correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change `this.props.handleContract` to `props.handleContract`. `this` doesn't exist in your functional component.

```
 const SearchResults = props => (
  <div>
    <div className="row" ><h4 style={{ margin: "auto", marginBottom: "15px" }}>Search Results:</h4></div>
    <table className="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {props.labels.map(label => (<th key={label.Id}>{label.DisplayName}</th>))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props.contracts.map((contract, i) => <tr key={i} data-id={contract.Id} onClick={() => props.handleContract(contract.Fields.filter(field => field.DataField === "IDXT001").map(field => field.DataValue))} className="clickable-row">{contract.Fields.map(docs => <td key={docs.Id}><span id={docs.DataField}>{docs.DataValue}</span></td>)}</tr>)}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

On your parent, make sure you have bound the onClick function as mentioned in the comments.

```
class SearchPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      labels: [],
      contracts: [],
      formValues: "",
      pdfs: [],
      id: ""
    };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    // Bind the function like this.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SearchResults
        labels={this.state.labels}
        contracts={this.state.contracts}
        pdfs={this.state.pdfs}
        handleContract={this.onClick}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You either have to bind your callback in the parent's constructor or in the component's scope.

Comment: That makes sense. But now I get a "props.handleContract is not a function" error.

Comment: Why do you have bunch of login inside handleContract invoke? `onClick={() => props.handleContract(contract.Fields.filter(field => field.DataField === "IDXT001").map(field => field.DataValue))}`

Comment: This is the third layer of a api call. It is used to extract the data from a specific Id in a dynamic input. Is that what you mean?